# No module called 'discord' found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot. So I did 'pip install discord' and it installed successfully! I have added Python to PATH as well. now in the Python Shell, I typed, 'import discord'. Then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I have used 'pip install discord' again and again and it still doesn't work! My pip is also the latest version. I also uninstalled and installed python but still doesn't work! :(

Why does it not work? Please help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Could you try the following in your terminal? "pip -V"

Comment: It's possible that you have more than one Python version installed.

Comment: firstly run "pip install discord.py" in your command prompt and import discord.py not just "discord"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because it is
`pip install discord.py` and not
`pip install discord`.
If you are on Linux, try `pip3 install discord.py` (`pip` installs to `python2` by default).

You can also see the official [pypi project](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/).

Comment: @Kaan I did and it says pip version 20.3.3 from the path and python 3.8

Comment: I did it but still same result :(

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: Yes - try pip3 if you're using latest python version.  If you're looking for a full guide, you can see this article: https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/how-to-build-a-discord-bot-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple solution. A previous answer indicated to make sure that you use the **correct, full module name** when making the pip call to install the module, and this is imperative -- however, since you're still not seeing results there is clearly still an issue.

The first question is **what is your python download**? Did you install python through something like conda, or did you just install the language directly on your device without a facilitating package?

In the meantime (and especially if you don't know the answer to the above question), try this command in your terminal (*not* your python shell, just your command line):

```
pip freeze
```

This command is referenced from [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-Python-modules) link, in case you're curious, and should give you a list of all locally install non-default python packages. If you provide the result of this call, I am certain it will better facilitate the solving of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Me to, I got this error.
I solved it as follows:

```
import discord.abc
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use linux and run the pip install command as non root but the start command as root you need to run the pip command also as root

Comment: When you'll get 50 reputation, remember to use comments for such tips.